# Addition of values in a 10x10 python pandas dataframe excluding the diagonal

Tags: python

Hi I have a data frame example below.  I want to add all off diagonal values to calculate a for a miss-classification score. This is 1-the miss-classification rate.  How to I add all the off diagonal values up?

[image: dataframe]

I have tried this code.

```
1-(my_LINEARSVC_cross.ix[0,4]+my_LINEARSVC_cross.ix[4,0])/np.sum(my_LINEARSVC_cross.values)
```

How can I ammend this to add all the off diagonal values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply compute the sum of whole matrix minus its trace (sum of a diagonal), which in numpy would be

```
m.sum() - m.trace()
```

so if its a pandas frame you can convert it

```
import numpy as np
m = np.array(my_LINEARSVC_cross)
print m.sum() - m.trace()
```

or take out through `.values`

```
print my_LINEARSVC_cross.values.sum() - my_LINEARSVC_cross.values.trace()
```

Comment: Since `my_LINEARSVC_cross` is a DataFrame, not an ndarray, the OP will probably need to add `.values`, i.e. `.values.sum()` and `.values.trace()`.

Comment: Thank you.  This was very helpful.